# Regular expression not working in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match the following 2 patterns.

- 12345
- 12345.67890

The regular expression I'm using is `^[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{5}.[0-9]{5}$`. It is working for the first pattern but not the second. I have tested with Regex tester for .net and it is working. Can someone let me know what is wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `^([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{5}\.[0-9]{5})$`

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and that did not actually work for me. You should specify that '.' is a literal.

This works:

```
([0-9]{5})(\.[0-9]{5})?
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use.

```
([0-9]{5})(\.[0-9]{5})*
```

You can test yours own regex expression in: https://regexr.com/

**EDIT**:

```
([0-9]{5})(\.[0-9]{5})|([0-9]{5})
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it matches the fractional part 0 or more times. Eg. `12345.45678.12345` will match here.